# Not suitable value for terraform variable given the type declaration

Tags: terraform

I have a module that accepts the following variable

```
variable "policy" {
  description = "The policy to be created"
  type = map(list(object({
    path = string
    capabilities = list(string)
  })))
}
```

I am then calling the above module from another one

```
module "policies" {
  source = "../path/to/module/above"

  for_each = var.policies.policies
 
  policy = each.value

}
```

Where `var.policies` is declared in `terragrunt.hcl`

```
locals {
  policies = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))
}

inputs = {
  policies = local.policies
}
```

and `config.yaml`

```yaml
policies:
  policy-test-1:
    - capabilities:
        - read
        - create
      path: /foo/lala
    - capabilities:
        - read
        - create
      path: /bar/lala
  policy-test-2:
    - capabilities:
        - update
        - delete
      path: /foo/lala
```

This fails:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│
│   on main.tf line 38, in module "policies":
│   38:   policy = each.value
│
│ The given value is not suitable for
│ module.policies["policy-test-2"].var.policy declared at
│ ../path/to/module/above/variables.tf:5,1-18: map of
│ list of object required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│
│   on main.tf line 38, in module "policies":
│   38:   policy = each.value
│
│ The given value is not suitable for
│ module.policies["policy-test-1"].var.policy declared at
│ ../path/to/module/above/variables.tf:5,1-18: map of
│ list of object required.
```

Why isn't `each` `var.policies.policies` a map of list of objects? Isn't supposed to be an

```
policy-test-1 : {
  [
    {
      capabilities = ["create", "read"]
      path         = "/foo/lala"
    },
    {
      capabilities = ["create", "read"]
      path         = "/bar/lala"
    }
  ]
}
```

which is a map (with key `policy-test-1`) of a list of objects, each object in the list being of

```
  {
    path = string
    capabilities = list(string)
  }
```

type?

Comment: could you please try `policy = {each.key)` and `policy = each.key` in your module interface instead of `policy=each.value`

Comment: same error in the output

Comment: try : `policy = {
capabilities = each.value.capabilities
path = each.value.path
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type for your `policy` is a **list**, not a map, because your `each.value` will be a `list`:

```
variable "policy" {
  description = "The policy to be created"
  type = list(object({
    path = string
    capabilities = list(string)
  }))
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: `│ The given value is not suitable for module.policies.var.policy declared at
│ ../path/to/module/above/variables.tf:5,1-18 list of
│ object required.`

Comment: @pkaramol This means that your real code is different that what you posted in the question, because my answers address the issue that you reported based on the examples and code you gave.

Comment: you are right, I had made a change in the mean time (I reverted it and it now works), sorry about that